# How to find the convergence interval and radius of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}(2x+5)^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the convergence interval and convergence radius of the sequence $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}(2x+5)^n.$$

I tried ratio test: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac {\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}(2x+5)^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]{n}(2x+5)^n}\right|=|(2x+5)|\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac {\sqrt[n+1]{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right|.$$

But couldn't conclude.

Comment: Hint: Try the comparison theorem. Also, test some values of $x$ to see when the summand converges to 0.

Comment: That will work. The limit is quite simple, since in fact $\sqrt[n]{n}$ has limit $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $$\sqrt[n]n(2x+5)^n\sim_\infty (2x+5)^n$$
so by the ratio test we have
$$\left|\frac{(2x+5)^{n+1}}{(2x+5)^n}\right|=|2x+5|<1\iff -3<x<-2$$
hence the radius is $\frac12$ moreover for $x=-3$ or $x=-2$ the series is divergent since the general term of the series doesn't converge to $0$ in these cases. We conclude that $(-3,-2)$ is the interval of the convergence of the given series.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost right, just log the expressions:
$$
\frac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}} \rightarrow \frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1} - \frac{\log n}{n} \to_n0-0=0
$$
hence the limit of the ration is $e^0=1$. So allyou need to do is check $|2x+5|<1$.